# Purpose of current, voltage and resistance

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Since in a circuit, it is the electromagnetic field which transports energy from the source to the electrical components, and that in a circuit, the electrons barely move, what is the point of calculating current, voltage, and resistance? Wouldn't the current be extremely small due to the incredibly small drift speeds of electrons?

Answer (score 4):

> Wouldn't the current be extremely small due to the incredibly small drift speeds of electrons?

Not necessarily. There are a lot of free electrons in a typical conductor, so even small drift speeds lead to large currents. Of course “small” and “large” are rather ambiguous anyway. They are large enough to do whatever the circuit was designed to do.

> Since in a circuit, it is the electromagnetic field which transports energy … what is the point of calculating current, voltage, and resistance?

Even though the fields carry the energy, there is a theorem in electromagnetism that says that under some conditions the total amount of power transferred into a device is the sum of the currents times the voltages at the points where the currents enter the device. It is a very convenient and useful simplification because it gives you a nice simple scalar equation to use instead of dealing with field integrals.

Answer (score 2):

The question has two components: 1. what is the point of calculating current, voltage and resistance? and 2. given that the electrons move so slowly, why isn't the current extremely small?

*Answer to 1.*

The current, voltage and resistance are the main concepts for getting an understanding of circuits at the large scale of the circuit elements themselves, and this in turn enables us to understand more complicated things such as complicated networks of components, the role of transistors and amplifiers, and so on and so forth. Indeed an electrical engineer tasked with designing a high-power amplifier or a power station or a c.d. player etc. does not need to know anything about electrons!

*Answer to 2.*

Compare the following two situations:

1. some speed-boats and jet-skis whizzing about the sea, heading towards the harbour
2. a line of slow-moving inflatable rings drifting on the current, all jostling next to each other, each carrying one package.

Even though the inflatable rings may be moving slowly, if they are packed densely enough then they can transport a LOT more goods, per unit time, than all those speed-boats and jet-skis.

It is similar with electrons and current. Even though the electrons just drift slowly along the wires, they are so densely packed together that they deliver a lot of charge all together. For a 100 amp current we would need $6 \times 10^{20}$ electrons to pass a given plane per second. The electrons are so densely packed
(about $10^{29}$ per m$^3$ in copper)
that in a wire of cross-section 1 cm$^2$ they only need to drift along at $0.06$ mm/s in order to deliver this 100 amps. So the lesson is: do not think that this small speed means it is so slow as to be negligible! It is only slow compared to our everyday experience of speed. But it cannot be ignored because it delivers a large current.

If I was swimming by a harbour wall and an ocean liner coming in to dock was approaching me at $0.06$ mm/s then I would be right to be worried. I would be in desperate need to get out of the way!

Answer (score 0):

> Since in a circuit, it is the electromagnetic field which transports
> energy from the source to the electrical components, and that in a
> circuit, the electrons barely move, what is the point of calculating
> current, voltage, and resistance?

The electrons may "barely move", but in conductors there are a huge number of electrons that move. See below.

> Wouldn't the current be extremely small due to the incredibly small
> drift speeds of electrons?

Not in the case of conductors. That's because in the case of conductors the number of free electrons available to pass through a surface per unit volume is huge. The relationship between current and average drift velocity is

$$I=neAv_{d}$$

where

$n$ = the number of mobile charges (electrons) per unit volume (8.4 x 10$^{22}$ for copper)

$A$= cross sectional area of conductor

$e$ = charge per electron (1.602 x 10$^{-19}$ coulombs)

$v_d$ = average electron drift velocity.

For example, for a 1 mm diameter copper wire carrying 1 ampere (coulomb/sec) of current, the average electron drift velocity is 0.93504 x 10$^{-4}$ m/sec.

For a more detailed discussion see:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Hope this helps.